# Making sure an input is of a certain type with jQuery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-input

I'm trying to loop over all inputs in my form that are either "text" or "file".

Here's my form markup:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="upload_form">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Skin name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="desc">Skin description:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="desc" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="aname">Authors name:</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="aname" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="aname">Skin image file:</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="skin" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </p>
</form>
```

I basically want to check all of these inputs apart from the submit button. Here's my code so far:

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {
    $('#upload_form input').each(function(index) {
        if( this.type == "input" ) {

        }
    });
});
```

But it's wrong, I know. Can anyone tell me how to iterate over each input that is either a text or file input?

Thanks.

Comment: `this[0].type == "text"` should work but I think there is a fancy jQuery way for this as well

Comment: If I use `if( this[0].type == "text" ) {` the if never evaluates to true :(

Comment: What about using the property 'tagName'? http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-how-to-get-the-tag-name/

Comment: What about `$($(this).attr('type').split()).get(0) == 'text'`? That's jQuery enough right?

Comment: @Pekka: In the `.each()`, `this` will be a direct reference to the DOM element. :o)

Comment: @Roatin: Not even close. You really need to get rid of the awful `==`. This is a much better solution: `$('<div>').text($($(this).attr('type').split()).get(0)).filter(':contains("text")').size()`

Comment: @patrick dw: Lets make it a plugin, for extra jQuery-fu points: `(function($) { $.fn.isTypeEquals = function(type) { return this.filter(function() { return $('<div>').text($($(this).attr('type').split()).get(0)).filter(':contains("' + type + '")').size() > 0 }) } }(jQuery))`

Comment: @Roatin: Ah yes, much better. And to think someone would actually write `this.type`. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *filter* or the *not* selector to accomplish this.

I believe you could do this:

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {
    $('#upload_form input').not(':submit').each(function(index) {
        ...
    });
});
```

I think this would also work:

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(e) {
    $('#upload_form input').filter('[type=text], [type=file]').each(function(index) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.tagName`  It will give you the tag type as an uppercase string.

Comment: Just tried this: `alert(this.tagName);` and all it alerts is `INPUT`. Unless I'm using it incorrectly this isn't what I need, I need a way to iterate over inputs of type "text" or "file".

Comment: Ah, then this.attr('type') will contain the information you want.  Also, the answer from @Chris Schmitz contains a solution I believe will be more efficient.